# Highlighting whole lines in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to highlight a whole line in a RichTextBox. Right now I have this method

```
if (Current != null)
{
    selectStart = this.textBox.Text.Length;
    foreach (string s in Current.Details)
    {
        this.textBox.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    selectEnd = this.textBox.Text.Length;
    this.textBox.Select(selectStart, selectEnd - selectStart);
    this.textBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(51, 255, 51);
}
```

But this results with only highlighting the text, as shown here:
[image]

I want the code to highlight the whole line length. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Maybe you could use a listbox and override paint event?

Comment: Not really. I need it to be a RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want to do as the RichTextBox does not support the box model (like browsers would with a `<div>` block). It will only ever decorate the text itself.